# Flex tooltip disappears when button is Clicked

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have tooltips in flex but when a component is clicked the tooltip disappears and the user has to move mouse out of the control and then back into the control to display the tooltip.

Is there a way to prevent the tooltip from getting destroyed on mouse click.

I tried calling 
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
e.preventDefault(); on mouse click event of button. also tried handling and preventing tooltipEnd and tooltipHide events but they are not fire when the button is clicked.

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't expect anything you do w/ the click event should prevent the toolTip for vanishing [although it may if you put your listener in the capture phase; but if you cancel in the capture phase I'm not sure the button will be clickable].  Show us the code of how you add listeners for toolTipEnd and toolTipHide and what your actual attempt is for preventing the removal of toolTip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by adding a event handler to the mouseDown event and then calling preventDefault and stopImmediatePropagation there this prevents the tooltip from vanishing and the button is still clickable.